# Inserting script generated columns into HTML generated columns

Tags: php, jquery

I generated two fixed size columns with HTML, then I tried to insert a column created from and including data from an AJAX/JSON/jsquery script. There is room between the HTML columns for the script generated column and I included the same style code in the script.

HTML file style for columns:

```
    .column {
      float: left;
      padding: 10px;
      min-height: 600px; 
      top: 190px;
      position:fixed;
    }

    .col1 {
      width: 200px; 
      left: 0px;    
    }
    .col2 {
      width: 100px; 
      left: 230px;
    }
    .col3 {
      width: 120px; 
      left: 350px;; /*keep checkboxes close to column 2 text boxes*/
    }
```

HTML code for column #1:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column col1"  style="background-color:#aaa;">
            <form method="POST" action="ReadFrmData.php">
                Value:  <input type="text" style = "width: 100px"name="sdata" 
    value=" "><br>
            <input type="radio" name="Set" value="SetPos1"> Set Pos1 <br> 
                <input type="radio" name="Set" value="SetPos2"> Set Pos2<br>
                <input type="submit" name="sendset" value="Send"><br>
        </form>
        </div>
```

HTML code for column #3:

```
    <div class="column col3" style="background-color:#ccc;">
            <form method="POST" action="ReadFrmData.php">
                <h4>Request<br>Configuration</h4><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Req1" value="SetReq1"><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Req2" value="SetReq2"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="sendconfig" value="Send"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The AJAX/JSON/jsquery script for column #2:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--Put the following in the <head>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(){
    $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
    var data = {"action": "test"};
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $(".the-return").html("<div class='column col2' style='background-color:#bbb;position:fixed; width: 100px; left: 240px;'>"+
            "<h4>Data</h4>" +
            "<form><br><br>" +
            "<input type='text' style='height: 14px ; width: 100px' value= " + data['Pos1'] + "><br>" +
            "<input type='text' style='height: 14px; width: 100px' value = " + data['Pos2'] + "><br>" +
            "</form></div>"
            );
        }
      });
    return false;
    });
    });
```

I am trying to insert the script generated column 2 between the HTML generated columns 1 and 3 but nothing happens. The HTML works by itself and the script can generate a column when tested with just a start button and no other code.

Comment: hi there, you tagged it with php, in fact this is javascript and html

Answer (score 0):

test if your script is responding to any submit action with `alert();`. I don't see any submit button with the class attribute `".js-ajax-php-json"`. Also where is `".the-return"`? I don't see anything in your table with that class either.

In your Table you should specify a div or an element you want to insert your ajax response into.
Ex:

```
HTML code for column #1:
<div class="row">
    <div class="column col1"  style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <form method="POST" action="ReadFrmData.php">
            Value:  <input type="text" style = "width: 100px"name="sdata" 
value=" "><br>
        <input type="radio" name="Set" value="SetPos1"> Set Pos1 <br> 
            <input type="radio" name="Set" value="SetPos2"> Set Pos2<br>
            <input type="submit" name="sendset" value="Send"><br>
    </form>
    </div>

<div id="column2">AJAX RESPONSE HERE</div>

HTML code for column #3:
<div class="column col3" style="background-color:#ccc;">
        <form method="POST" action="ReadFrmData.php">
            <h4>Request<br>Configuration</h4><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Req1" value="SetReq1"><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Req2" value="SetReq2"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="sendconfig" value="Send"><br>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

In your AJAX call, specify id `column2` to return the response:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#column2").html("<div class='column col2' style='background-color:#bbb;position:fixed; width: 100px; left: 240px;'>"+
        "<h4>Data</h4>" +
        "<form><br><br>" +
        "<input type='text' style='height: 14px ; width: 100px' value= " + data['Pos1'] + "><br>" +
        "<input type='text' style='height: 14px; width: 100px' value = " + data['Pos2'] + "><br>" +
        "</form></div>"
        );
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you have an element with the class ".the-return".  You need a place for your new html to go.  There are many ways to accomplish this using jquery.

Without completely re-writing your code, you could simply set your html as a variable, and insert it after your first column using the jquery insertAfter().  [See here for more info](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/).

This should work.

```
var column2 = $("<div class='column col2' style='background-color:#bbb;position:fixed; width: 100px; left: 240px;'>" +
    "<h4>Data</h4>" +
    "<form><br><br>" +
    "<input type='text' style='height: 14px ; width: 100px' value= " + data['Pos1'] + "><br>" +
    "<input type='text' style='height: 14px; width: 100px' value = " + data['Pos2'] + "><br>" +
    "</form></div>");

column2.insertAfter('.col1');
```

Comment: Thanks! You nailed it. I forgot to copy that over from the test script!!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help!